# sql server how to display data which is in the month of august?

Tags: mysql, sql

hello guys i have a small problem with my sql code
i have to only display data in the database which is in the month of august 2008.

my code so far is this

i am supposed to show the sales of each sales person in the month of august 2008

SELECT   p.BusinessEntityID,p.FirstName,p.LastName, ROUND(SUM(soh.TotalDue),2) AS 'Total Attributed Sales'
    FROM Person.Person p , Sales.SalesPerson s,Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
    WHERE  p.BusinessEntityID = s.BusinessEntityID
    AND p.BusinessEntityID = soh.SalesPersonID
    AND soh.OrderDate >= '2008' AND soh.OrderDate < '2009'
    GROUP BY p.BusinessEntityID,P.FirstName,P.LastName
    ORDER BY p.LastName

i have the image of my database
http://www.2shared.com/photo/h2-jMQyP/AdventureWorks2008.html

Comment: what is the structure of your tables? Do you have a column with date? or columns with Year and Month?

Comment: We need a bit more information about your database, I would presume in the [Sales] table you store a date of some sort? where is the date stored which you are going to filter? and what format is it stored?

Comment: @ Uriel_SVK, @kamui
please check the edited version of my question

Comment: I don't understand your edited question: do you want us to write the whole query for you reading that schema? No...

Comment: @Marco i'm supossed  include the sales  of each person in the month of august 2008 i dnt understand your code

Comment: My code was written to provide an example with your previous question; now you've just edited it, changing the request....

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.BusinessEntityID,p.FirstName,p.LastName
FROM Person.Person p INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson s
    ON p.BusinessEntityID = s.BusinessEntityID
WHERE MONTH(p.your_date) = 8
  AND YEAR(p.your_date) = 2008
```

Just a note: when you have to join tables use `JOIN` statement in place of `WHERE`; sql engine  here understands you're joining tables and convert execution plan to use a `JOIN`, but in other situations you risk doing tables cartesian product, making your query really huge!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your database structure, if you want to get the sales for a particular person you will probably have to add a link into SalesOrderHeader as well

**EDIT 2:** A slight modification to the script will get the total ammount due for all the sales for all sales people in august 2008

```
 SELECT p.BusinessEntityID,p.FirstName,p.LastName, SUM(soh.TotalDue)
 FROM Person.Person p , Sales.SalesPerson s,Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh

 WHERE  p.BusinessEntityID = s.BusinessEntityID
 AND s.BusinessEntityID = soh.BusinessEntityID

 AND MONTH(soh.OrderDate) = 8
 AND YEAR(soh.OrderDate) = 2008
 GROUP BY p.BusinessEntityID
```

Comment: @ kamui 
hey bro my question is
Write a query to find out the total attributed sales to each sales person for all SalesOrders placed in 2008. Use the TotalDue of the orders to find the sales amounts and the SalesPersonID to find the sales person to attribute. E.g. SalesOrderID 43659 should be attributed to SalesPersonID 279.

Comment: @ kamui 
i'm supposed to get 17 rows instead i get only 10 rows and sales figures are wrong

Comment: @user1297398 I presume some people are missing, did they have any sales in august of 2008? if they are not in all 3 tables then they will not come up in the results. Are all the results unique, they should be but maybe i'm missing something in the table structure.

Comment: @ kamui i can give you the right results as well, if you can give me your email id or something. and yeas all of the sales people are going to have sales in august

Comment: check your email bro sent it to you

Comment: Just out of curiosity what was the solution?

Comment: please check out my answer which i have edited in the question